# Can't find a bug here... C code

Tags: c, recursion, operator-precedence

In this code I tried to write a function which returns 0 value if the two strings don't match, and a length of matching characters if i can find a substring in str that wholey resambles patt.

```
#include....

int check(char *str, char *patt, int *b)
{   
    if (*str == *patt && *patt != 0)
        return *b * (1 + check(str+1,patt+1,&b));
    else if (*patt == 0)
        return 0;
    else{
        *b = 0;
        return 0;
    }
}

main()
{
    char s1[SIZE] = "mama";
    char s2[SIZE] = "mama";
    int b = 1;

    printf("%d\n",check(s1,s2,&b));
    b = 1;          

    system ("pause");
    return;
}
```

Here I should get the output 4, but I get -77779463.
Thanks for help!

PS I used recursion and set the b parameter as changable.

Comment: how about stepping through in a debugger?

Comment: Are you doing this simply as a learning exercise in recursion or is this your solution to the stated problem?

Comment: I tried, but I'm not so good at debugging.

Comment: SO is not an alternative to learning how to use a debugger.

Comment: Then consider this an opportunity to get better at it. Never take the attitude of "I'm not good at this so I should avoid it". Getting better requires practice.

Comment: It's a learning excercise, and part of a bigger code.

Comment: i tried debugging at least...

Comment: Also, a good thing would already to ask better questions. Your title just shows no effort of understanding your own problem. Voting to close.

Comment: TIP: turn compilers warning level up to maximum. Then fix ALL warnings...

Answer (score 7):

`b` is already a pointer to an `int`, so you want to make the recursive call with `b` and not `&b`.

Any decent compiler, with warnings enabled, would have alerted you to that mistake!

Comment: To add to this - if you're using `gcc`, make sure you're compiling with the `-Wall` switch enabled.

Answer (score 2):

```
return *b * (1 + check(str+1,patt+1,&b));
                                    ^ dont pass address.
```

Pass `b` to it instead.

Comment: THANKS!!! I got the warning but ignored, as i did previously...

Comment: (I'm a beginer so i thought warnings don't matter!)